# How to write multiline json record in pyspark?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I need to **write** a json file in multiline record format. Here's an example of the file that I'd like to generate from this object, pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame.

This generates a file containing json with single records.

```
df.write.mode('Overwrite').json("file.json")

{
  "RecordNumber": 2, "Zipcode": 704, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State": "PR"
}
{
  "RecordNumber": 10, "Zipcode": 709, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "BDA SAN LUIS","State": "PR"
}
```

Note, that square brackets or commas between records are missing. Desired file format containing multiple line json:

```
[{
  "RecordNumber": 2,
  "Zipcode": 704,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR",
  "State": "PR"
},
{
  "RecordNumber": 10,
  "Zipcode": 709,
  "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD",
  "City": "BDA SAN LUIS",
  "State": "PR"
}]
```

Comment: Your terminology is a bit odd.  What you're asking is not "multiple line json", it is proper JSON.  The first format is not proper JSON.  It's a set of JSON records.  The right way is to read in the old data, append the new data as a dict, and dump the modified structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to do it.  I load in the old JSON data, which gives me a list of dicts.  I convert the dataframe to dicts row by row, and extend the database with those dicts.  I think json.dump the resulting data.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

d1 = {
  "RecordNumber": 2, "Zipcode": 704, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "PASEO COSTA DEL SUR","State": "PR"
}
d2 = {
  "RecordNumber": 10, "Zipcode": 709, "ZipCodeType": "STANDARD", "City": "BDA SAN LUIS","State": "PR"
}

df = pd.DataFrame( [d1,d2] )

data = json.load(open('old.json'))
data.extend(list(d[1].to_dict() for d in df.iterrows()))
json.dump(data, open('new.json','w'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with Pyspark library and not pandas? The reason is that the file is very large and won't fit in memory as dataframe in pandas.

Comment: I'm not reading the file into a DataFrame.  I'm loading the JSON into a list of dicts, and appending the rows to that list.  You said the data was arriving in a DataFrame.  You don't need pandas at all if the new data is already a bunch of dicts.